# serving static files with pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am serving static files with `pm2` via `pm2 serve static PORTNUM`.
It works except, one issue I have is that I have a route called `http://webbite.com/search` and the webpage to serve is in `/search/index.html`. The problem is, `pm2` takes /search literally and looks for a file called `search` and not the `index.html` within the `search` directory.

Hence, I get this error:

> Error while serving /home/ubuntu/redacted/_site/school with
> content-type text/plain : EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
> read

Is there a setting I can pass in to `pm2` to let it know that if it's a directory, look for the `index.html` page in it?

Comment: Any update on this question? I have the same problem.

Comment: Please check edit queue (title should display "EISDIR error")